# Управление стеком Navigation Controller

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Возможно ли, исходя из данной схемы, осуществляя переходы `1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 5`, или же `1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5`, иметь возможность, находясь в `окне 5`, вернуться (три кнопки снизу `окна 5`) в тот же самый стек `1 -> 2` в открытое `окно 2` и перегрузить его с обновленными переданными параметрами. Чтобы в этом `окне 2` при нажатии на `back` снова возвращаться в том же самом стеке в `окно 1`?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Знаю, что есть способ вернуться по стеку на окно 2, но как в таком случае я смогу передать при этом нужные мне параметры? Или данное решение не позволяет их передавать?

```
UIViewController *prevVC = [self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
[self.navigationController popToViewController:prevVC animated:YES];
```

**ДОБАВЛЕНО:**
Как из `5` окна при осуществленном переходе `1 -> 5`, осуществить переход `5 -> 1 -> 2` ?

Comment: на вопрос как вернуться вы уже сами ответили, а как передать параметры - именно для этого у вас и есть модель (а если нет, то обязательно создайте :) )

Comment: Не совсем понял, что имеется ввиду под "модель"?
Временно сделал через NSUserDefaults :) работает, но ищу способ практичнее.

Comment: модель это 'M' из MVC :) короче какое то хранилище данных, которыми оперирует приложение. Это может быть класс/набор классов, база данных и так далее. NSUserDefaults фактически может использоваться как модель, но его прямая обязанность - хранение данных между сессиями.

Answer (score 1):

Тут надо просто найти способ передать данные, готового решения Cocoa не даёт, но можно решить вопрос в лоб при помощи банального программирования и объектно-ориентированного подхода. У тебя имеется стек вью-контроллеров, из него нужно вытащить конкретный объект и выставить ему нужные поля. Например

```
CustomViewController *callbackController = (CustomViewController *)self.navigationController.viewControllers[2];
callbackController.callbackProperty = callbackObject;
```

Это решение немного костыль, потому что требует жёстко определённого навигационного стека. Можно так же брать отступ от текущего вместо конкретной позиции, например

```
CustomViewController *callbackController = (CustomViewController *)self.navigationController.viewControllers[[self.navigationController.viewControllers indexOfObject:self] - 2];
```

Но это всё равно костыль.

---

Другой вариант - послать данные на нужный контроллер нотификацией (читай про `NSNotificationCenter`). Но опять же, тонкое место - нотификацию должен ловить только один объект, а если их несколько - как определить адресата?
Я предполагаю, что сториборд может иметь какие-нибудь механизмы возврата данных из сегуи, но с этим я ни разу не работал.

---

А теперь самый правильный ответ - контроллер при пуше других контроллеров должен передавать им объект, ответственный за возврат данных - это может быть блок, делегат или изменяемый объект в который уже в будущем другой контроллер положит данные перед "попом". Скорее всего последний вариант - это то, что тебе надо, ибо передавать блок/делегата через несколько пушей - это плохой тон, а вот объект возврата - самое оно.

Пример - есть объект `document`, у него есть заголовок. Главный контрноллер - это тот в котором документ просто просматривается, нажимаем на кнопку редактирования - `document` передаётся уже  контроллеру редактирования. Там наживается кнопка "Редактировать заголовок" и объект пошёл на контроллер ввода заголовка. Там пользователь вводи новый заголовок, нажимает Done, и перед "попом" в `document.title` записывается значение из текстового поля.